# Why is frame dragging possible for perfectly spherical spinning blackhole?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, frame-dragging

Even factoring the bulging as it spin very fast, I imagine no fluctuations in the density of gravitons emitting along the equator so how can frame dragging occurs? I know a gravitational wave depends on mass and frame dragging depends on spin instead, does it means the faster a black hole spins the event horizon actually shrinks and so frame dragging occurs?

Comment: I don't think trying to understand frame-dragging in terms of gravitons will help.  I'm not sure I understand it at all but I'm pretty sure that the approach would be to look at how it works in classical GR (which, after all, is the theory that predicts it).

Comment: Maybe this post addresses your question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/164636/why-cant-a-particle-rotate-opposite-to-the-central-mass-within-the-ergosphere/470890#470890, although the explanation relies on the Kerr metric, not on gravitational waves. And, yes the faster the BH spins the smaller the horizon radius, but mind (see post) that the frame dragging effect comes from the $g_{tt}$ component, not on the $g_{rr}$ (whose singularity marks the event horizon).

Comment: Spinning black holes are not spherical, and they do not radiate any gravitational waves. Frame dragging has nothing to do with gravitational waves or gravitons.